# Nautilus desktop folder menu bar and folders show up on secondary screen

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I have two monitors and I installed gnome shell in my fresh 11.10. For some reason the nautilus menus for the desktop folder appear in my secondary screen.

This never happened in my fedora 15. I don't know if it is a gnome 3.2 bug or an Ubuntu problem.

I've managed to disable it by making nautilus not handle the desktop via the gnome-tweak-tool, but that way I lose the capability to have icons on desktop.

[image: look]

Any ideas on how can I fix it, without disabling the gnome-tweak-tool option?

Comment: It is a known bug. Unless you're a developer, the only thing you can do is wait.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same problem and just removing the app-menu stuff from Unity (as you will never use this environment anymore) have made my day happier!

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt
```

Comment: A recent update to 11.10 made this start showing up for me in classic and your solution worked to get rid of it.