# Why does an additional top menu bar show off in Gnome fallback mode?

Tags: gnome, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nautilus desktop folder menu bar and folders show up on secondary screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66591/nautilus-desktop-folder-menu-bar-and-folders-show-up-on-secondary-screen)

Today I have updated Nautilus and LightDM (using the Update Manager), and after that, when I log into Gnome Classic, I always see an additional top bar menu, when the Gnome's top panel is hidden. This bar contains 6 menus: File, Edit, View, Go, Bookmarks and Help. How can I get rid of it? Did anyone of you have this kind of problem after an update?

Comment: i think your graphics driver is not in standard mode. Check from system Setings > System info > Graphics > Experience.  So try to fix graphics problem

Comment: It sounds like you are seeing the menu for Nautilus. Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/66591/18612

Answer (score 1):

That's Nautilus' menubar. It is used to display the desktop so you can store files and folders there, etc. It shouldn't be displayed, but it sometimes does anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to remove it is to install "gnome-tweak-tool" then to uncheck 'let file manager control the desktop' this will remove this bar but drive icons etc. will not now appear on the desktop. This has been fixed in 12.04 and the bar does not appear in classic.